# LWC - render HTML inside an HTML tag

Tags: lightning-web-components, html5

How do we render HTML inside a `div` tag?

Here is my `lightning-layout-item`:

```html
<lightning-layout-item class="slds-p-around_xxx-small" size="12">
    <div>{o.orderEntrySteps}</div>
</lightning-layout-item>
```

Here is the HTML I'm trying to render:

```html
<p><b style="font-size: 24px;">Details</b></p><ul><li style="text-align: justify;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li><li style="text-align: justify;">Aliquam non justo nec nisi scelerisque auctor fermentum non dui.</li><li style="text-align: justify;">Quisque facilisis metus id porttitor vestibulum.</li><li style="text-align: justify;">Aliquam ullamcorper odio et magna venenatis sodales.</li><li style="text-align: justify;">Suspendisse posuere massa in egestas laoreet.</li></ul><p><b style="font-size: 24px;">Steps</b></p><ol><li style="text-align: justify;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li><li style="text-align: justify;">Aliquam non justo nec nisi scelerisque auctor fermentum non dui.</li><li style="text-align: justify;">Quisque facilisis metus id porttitor vestibulum.</li><li style="text-align: justify;">Aliquam ullamcorper odio et magna venenatis sodales.</li><li style="text-align: justify;">Suspendisse posuere massa in egestas laoreet.</li><li style="text-align: justify;">Nulla tempor neque vulputate, venenatis tellus a, fermentum quam.</li><li style="text-align: justify;">Suspendisse cursus lorem vel orci feugiat, ut facilisis justo laoreet.</li><li style="text-align: justify;">Nullam vitae enim quis lectus venenatis dignissim.</li><li style="text-align: justify;">Morbi maximus tortor ac eleifend pulvinar.</li></ol>
```

If you put the above code into a HTML editor, it would be rendered like below. How do I get it rendered that way when I put it inside a div in my lightning web component?
[image]

Comment: To clarify: you mean `o.orderEntrySteps` is an HTML string?

Comment: That's right @MatthewSouther

Comment: Have you tried `lightning-formatted-rich-text`?

Comment: Just tried it, I am still not getting the rendered output, just plain HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [lightning-formatted-rich-text](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-rich-text/documentation) component to render the HTML.

This component supports the tags in your example, such as `b`, `p`, `ol`, and `ul`.  Depending on your actual HTML, you will want to check the docs to make sure all tags you intend to use are supported.

Comment: Just tried it, I am still not getting the rendered output, just plain HTML

Comment: I just tried your HTML string with `lightning-formatted-rich-text` and it worked in my dev org.  I had to escape all double quote characters, i.e. replacing `"` with `\"`.

Comment: How did you replace the " with \?

Comment: I did it with find/replace in VS Code, but you could use `replaceAll()` to do the same at runtime, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll

Comment: Thanks Matthew .It worked, but still need to work on it